# Mongodb time series data and time zone handling

Tags: node.js, mongodb, time-series, momentjs, data-modeling

I'm creating using node.js and mongodb an application that stores all temperature values by hour in a day.
Temperature values should be shown in a dashboard according the timezone where the sensor is located. 
I created a data model following the recommendation for time series data but I don't know how to deal with timezone because mongodb stores dates in UTC so in my data model the object "hours" has static fields for every hour of the day.

```
// Temperatures by hour in a day.
{
 dateStart: ISODate("2016-08-06T00:00:00.000Z"), // This is the start of the day
 timeZone: "Europe/Madrid", // We could store the time zone of the sensor.
 hours: {  // I'm not sure how to deal with these values. Should be UTC hours too?
  0: 20
  1: 21,
  2: 24,
  .
  .
  .
  23: 16
 }
}
```

**The question is: how can I deal with timezone?**

In my local time the start of a day (2016-08-06T00:00:00) is converted to UTC to 2016-08-05T22:00:00.000+02:00.

A first approach could be:

1. Sensor time zone is 'Europe/Madrid' (CEST, 02:00 diff from UTC)
2. Get the start of day using 'Europe/Madrid time zone, convert it to UTC and store it in database. Field startDate will be "2016-08-05T22:00:00.000Z"
3. In order to store a 25 C temperature for an hour: Get local time ('Europe/Madrid'), for example 18h, then convert to UTC. Result is 16h. So hours.16=25.

**In this case we have UTC times in star date but the object of hours is not UTC. It is 'Europe/Madrid and I'm not very convinced about this decision.**

**Any ideas for improving this design?**

Answer (score 0):

Your design should work, however your example in 3. should be

```
{
   ...
   16: 25
   ...
}
```

The hours is the **offset** respect to dateStart. So when displaying you should add 16 hours to the start date which you can display in the timezone that you want.

Comment: If I'm not wrong by using hours as offsets then I can't use static fields because different sensors in different timezones will have different structures inside field "hours". (by the way I've edited the example, correct local time is 18h while UTC is 16h)